# Detect backspace event on contenteditable div before the action of key is fired

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have tried using the `keydown` function, which seems to evaluate the `innerHTML` of the `div` before the letter is typed. However, when using the `Backspace` key it evaluates the `innerHTML` of the `div` after the backspace as been applied. Why is this? Is there another event I can use that will detect the backspace before it is applied?
**Key event vs input on screen**

```
Event      | Letter | Backspace |
---------------------------------
keydown    | before |   after   |
keypress   | before |   null    |
keyup      | after  |   after   |
input      | after  |   null    |
befpreinput| before |   null    |
```

**CODE**

```
element.addEventListener("input",inputReg)

function inputReg(e){
   console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: "_Why_" The input event would be pretty useless, if you don't know what was actually inputted. [beforeinput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) is probably what you're looking after?

Comment: didnt work. im wondering why it detects the event on a character before text, but not for backspace. i think thats a valid question.

Comment: Please tell me more about `beforeinput` ["_didn't work_"](https://jsfiddle.net/d6pxeyr5/) ... I didn't say the question wouldn't be valid. Notice, that `input` is not a Keyboard Event.

Comment: added it to the grid, it doesnt register on backspace

Comment: Your browser is in need of update if `beforeinput` doesn't fire. It works fine for me on the linked fiddle.

Comment: ya thats weird, it worked for me too. i am attaching the event listener as i create the elements. could it be that I am not storing the event listener in a variable?

Comment: Maybe you expect these events to behave differently from how they're designed to behave, and you should ask a new question about the specific programming problem you're facing with the events ..?

Comment: Like said above, `beforeinput` and `input` events are not Keyboard Events, they're [Input Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent). `data` property of `InputEvent` object contains the entered data, but only in case it's character data, backspace and other non-printable characters are not included.